# ValueError logits and labels must have the same shape (?, 10) vs (2,2,?,10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, valueerror

I want to update a simple neural network using 2 LSTM cells.
Old architecture (that worked): Input => RNN => Output
New architecture (with value error): Input => LSTM => LSTM => Output

```
layers = 2
units = 10
outputs = 10
X = tf.placeholder (tf.float32,[None,nr_steps, nr_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder (tf.float32,[None,outputs])
cells = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell (num_units = units)
        for _ in range(layers)]
neurons = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(cells)
rnn_outputs, rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn (neurons, X, dtype = tf.float32)
```

with a `BasicRNNCell` the code worked, but, after this transformation, I received the error

```
ValueError Shapes (?, 10) and (2,2,?,10) must have the same rank
ValueError Shapes (?, 10) and (2,2,?,10) are not compatible
ValueError logits and labels must have the same shape Shapes (?, 10) vs (2,2,?,10)
```

Can anyone help me? I think the first **2** from (**2**,2,?,10) comes from the LSTM cells (but why?) and the second **2** from (2,**2**, ?,10) comes from the two layers of the network (but why?) and how can I handle this error?

Comment: Please, provide us with a [**minimal**, **complete**, and **verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is the minimal code which information do you also need? the problem occurs in the last line rnn_outputs,rnn_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn

Comment: I cannot execute your code. I would need to add imports, sessions, etc. You need to provide also that, i.e. the example must be complete and verifiable too.